# C++ Breaking DWORD into characters

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, memory

I have a four byte DWORD that I need to split into four different characters. I thought I knew how to accomplish this but am getting bizarre numbers every time. Here is my code:

```
    // The color memory
    int32 col = color_mem[i];

    // The four destination characters
    char r, g, b, a;

    // Copy them in advancing by one byte every time
    memcpy(&r, &col, 1);
    memcpy(&g, &col + 1, 1);
    memcpy(&b, &col + 2, 1);
    memcpy(&a, &col + 3, 1);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ditch the `memcpy` and use bit manipulation:

```
r = (col & 0x000000ff);
g = (col & 0x0000ff00) >>  8;
b = (col & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
a = (col & 0xff000000) >> 24;
```

`ff` in the hexadecimal numbers represents a byte of all `1` bits. This and the `&` - bitwise AND - will make the bytes that you're not interested in - at each position - `0`, and keeping the bits that you are interested in.

The `>>` shifts in zeros from the left, putting the byte that we want in the most significant position, for the actual assignment. A shift of 8 shifts by a width of one byte, 16 is two bytes, and 24 is three bytes.

Visually, looking at `ff`, you can imagine that we're walking the byte indices towards the left.

Comment: Can you recommend a good tutorial on this subject? Seems like something I should definitely know.

Comment: any good C book will cover this, look at K&R's _The C Programming Language_. Also one [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html)

Comment: As posted this will work if the byte ordering is big-endian; on little-endian platforms (x86, x64, etc), you will need to reverse things in order to match the OP's intent: `a = (col & 0xff000000) >> 24; 
b = (col & 0x00ff0000) >> 16; 
g = (col & 0x0000ff00) >>  8; 
r = (col & 0x000000ff);`

Comment: Since most of us use little-endian hardware, you'll probably want to reverse the order of these to achieve the desired result of the OP, who is expecting the memory to be organised as RGBA, not ABGR as in your post.

Answer (score 4):

When you do pointer arithmetic, the amount of the increment or decrement is multiplied by the size of the type being pointed to.  Cast the `int32` pointer to a `char` pointer in order to access `char` sized parts at some offset from the base address of `col`.

This technique can be fragile due to differences in endian-ness on different platforms, so I recommend using the more portable bitmask operations supplied in another answer.

```
// The color memory  
int32 col = color_mem[i];  

// The four destination characters  
char r, g, b, a;  

// Copy them in advancing by one byte every time  
memcpy(&r, (char*)&col, 1);  
memcpy(&g, ((char*)&col) + 1, 1);  
memcpy(&b, ((char*)&col) + 2, 1);  
memcpy(&a, ((char*)&col) + 3, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding +1 to a int32 will make the address go up 4 bytes.

You could use `memcpy(&g, reinterpret_cast<char *>(&col)+1, 1)` and so on.

Better way:

```
int32 col = color_mem[i];

struct splitted4byte
{
    char r;
    char g;
    char b;
    char a;
}

splitted4byte rgb;

memcpy(&rgb, &col, 4);
```

You should care about the order of the bytes in the `col` by the way. I don't know which part of the int32 is which color.

You should read up about endianness. (google it, there are documentations)

When R highest value and other colors are 0, if it is stored as `1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`, I mean if integer representation of the color RGBA(255,0,0,0) equals to this binary value. It will be reverse ordered in the memory, which is `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111`, therefore you need to calculate this.

You could use network conversion functions that converts network-byte-order (big-endian) to host-machine byte-order (either little endian or still big endian). This way you won't need to change your code according to the machine. (the function is ntohl (network to host long), there is also htons (host to network short) and such for 2-byte, there is also be64toh() for 64-bit integers, but the function only exits on Unix variants if I remember right.)
All you will need to do is `int32 col = ntohl(color_mem[i]);`

Or you could make your struct order according to this, but that way your code won't work on big-endian.

Answer (score 1):

since col is an int32 +1 adds an offset of 4 bytes

search for pointer arithmetics on google

Answer (score 1):

Everyone's given different answers, and all are correct in one way or another.  Some are endian-specific (as in doing bitwise operations).  Others are not.  For clarity, I might do this:

```
char *bytes = (char*)&color_mem[i];
char r = bytes[0];
char g = bytes[1];
char b = bytes[2];
char a = bytes[3];
```

I don't see any reason to use `memcpy`.  Even with structures.  Structure-assignment is a language feature - you don't have to copy it.

Haven't seen any mention of unions yet...

```
union Pixel {
    DWORD packed;
    struct Components {
        char r, g, b, a;
    };
    char bytes[4];
};

// You can just specify your image data like this...
Pixel *pixels = (Pixel*)color_mem;

// Reference one pixel for convenience - don't need to reference, you can
// just copy it instead if you want (alternative: Pixel p = pixels[i])
Pixel &p = pixels[i];

char r = p.r;
char g = p.g;
char b = p.b;
char a = p.a;

int32 col = p.packed;
```

This is endian-neutral: It does not rely on the organisation of an integer.  Usually this is fine, but you still need to be conscious of it.